# Using Google Classroom Share button to add assignment

Tags: google-classroom

I own a website and have created several quizes for teachers to give to their students about the info on my site. I wanted to help make it easier for teachers to use by having a button to add the quiz to their Google classroom. I figured out how to make the button, and then set out to convert my quiz into a Google Form.

I was all excited because I realized I could make the form self grading, which would really make it easy for teachers. I finished my form and put the share button on my website. However the problem is that when teachers assign the quiz, I get the results instead of the teacher. It's like it's just linking the students to MY form instead copying the form into the classroom for the teacher to use.

Anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing any of your code.

Comment: What code? I don't have source code for the Google form... And the share button is simply including a is file from Google.

Answer (score 0):

### I get the results instead of the teacher

[image]

When you enable the option `Get email notifications for new responses` - the notifications will be received by default by the person who created the quiz - you.

### having a button to add the quiz to their Google classroom

This means providing a link to fill out the form - the from owner who is going to receive the notification emails will still be you.

### created several quizes for teachers to give to their students

What you can do is to add the teachers as collaborators of your form.

[image]

In this case, each of the collaborators - including you, can tick or untick individually the option of receiving notification emails.

HOWEVER: all collaborators who opt for receiving notifications will not only receive notifications about new responses from their classroom, but about all new responses.

### CONCLUSION

What you need to share your form with all teachers (as collaborators) and ask them to make a copy of it.

[image]

- Each teacher will be the only owner of his copy and the only receiver of notification emails.
- Each teacher needs to create his own `Send form` link and add it to his class room. 
  [image]
- Each teacher should also set his own destination spreadsheet for responses

[image]

If you want to automatize the process, you need to write a script that creates an individual copy for each teacher who clicks on your sharing button, but this requires  coding (e.g. Google Apps Script).